# How can I use ActiveWorkbook/Workbooks(name) without getting a Runtime Error 91 in Excel 2013 VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

While this is not the first time I wrote macros like this, I cant seem to figure out how I get this to work. I have a snipped below that I think *should* work but doesn't.

My problem is that while at the beginning of my work day the snipped worked exactly *once*, but afterwards I always get the **Runtime Error '91: object variable or with-block variable not set** error message.

I have two workbooks opened, and I selected cells within the workbook I wanted to work with *manually* before starting the macro.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim source, sheet As Worksheet
Dim sourcename As String
Dim targetname As String
Dim test As Workbook
Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Activate
test = ActiveWorkbook
Debug.Print (test.Name)

sourcename = "Tabelle1"
targetname = "Tabelle2"

Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sourcename)
Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(targetname)

Debug.print(sheet.Name)
Debug.print(source.Name)

End Sub
```

The error occurs in the line containing `test = ActiveWorkbook`

**EDIT:** After the initial `Set`error was fixed, the *sheet* and *source* variables are still empty, thus each is causing another error of this type.

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have found these questions that seem related, however I can't see them working in my case: [getting error “Object Variable or With block variable not set”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691458/getting-error-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) and [VBA run-time error ‘91’: Object variable or With block variable not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551262/vba-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set)

Comment: Both those Q's point you at the answer: use `Set`

Comment: @chrisneilsen yes, In this case it seems I just needed a second pair of eyes, as I have been looking at this for two hours even though I have used the very same methods  a dozen times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

1st- do not give the same name to both Variable and Sub, you have 'Test' for both

2nd- add `Set` before this line `test = ActiveWorkbook` like
`Set test = ActiveWorkbook`

**remember- change Sub name into anything other then `test`**

Comment: It seems that while the Error is removed at first, my example was flawed: After the `set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sourcename)` the variable is still empty, according to the debugger

Comment: copy - paste your current code to question with changed name and `set` added where required. Next I will try to help again